# Source code on GitHub (failed review)

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

Review question: [iOS 7, corrupt UINavigationBar when swiping back fast using the default interactivePopGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5138380)

I'm not sure a question that includes a link to GitHub for the source files makes a good audit question.

It seems to me the question should be closed as *"what's wrong with this code" without providing the relevant source code*.

(Adding the [support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support) in case its decided the question should be removed from the review pool).

Comment: I agree, questions with just a JSFiddle link are not acceptable without accompanying code.

Comment: Close vote audits come from the set of questions that are unanimously upvoted (no downvotes). You can detect these by noticing when you get a review for a question with a relatively high number of upvotes (more than 5 or so) - open the question in a new tab, check if it actually has any close votes and check its up/down vote count. When you identify an audit, you can downvote it if you don't agree, skip, or vote to leave open.

Comment: Thanks @gnat - I was not aware of that tag. (And don't read into 'dispute' too strongly. I'm not complaining... just trying to get it out of the review pool).

Comment: [there you go](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773 "Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection") then, with 2 downvotes it's certainly [out of close/reopen audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168366/failed-a-reopen-question-audit-sure-looks-like-not-a-real-question-to-me/168372?noredirect=1#comment771109_168372) now, and quite likely won't pollute other queues as well.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused.  The OP explained what they were going through, what was happening, why they suspected that it was a lower level bug than was first believed, provided source code (eventually) to demonstrate their case, and seemed to just about exhaust all other avenues of help or resource location.  Just **what** is wrong with this question??

Comment: @Makoto  - I stated what was wrong in the question. I also examined the issue in it in greater detail in the answer below.

Answer (score 18):

The OP did everything right.  He's trouble-shooting a vexing interaction in a framework that's used by tens of thousands of programmers.  He documented what he saw happening, created a video for everybody to see and showed a workaround he was not happy with.  He got acknowledgement that this issue is real in the comments.

Then, especially for the issue, created a Github account so he could share a minimum repro with everybody.  And burned up a significant chunk of his rep on a bounty to keep the issue alive.  This did eventually produce a pretty decent workaround that he was happy with.

This is **exactly** what an SO questioner should do to tackle a nasty problem like this in code he didn't write.  His dogged insistence and energy he expended on finding a solution is admirable and will be very useful to anybody that encounters the same problem.  I have no idea why you thought it was appropriate to vote to close.  I suspect the warning you got from the failed review was appropriate: Stop, Look, Listen.  You probably didn't look or just robo-reviewed on "hey, there's a link".

You failed this audit for a very good reason, you got it wrong.  Big time wrong.  Small odds that you'll discover the question was right until *you* get stuck on the exact same problem.  Never ever ignore the Skip button.

Comment: "You probably didn't look or just robo-reviewed on "hey, there's a link"" - actually, no. As I stated in the question, relevant source code was not provided. Plus, I don't follow offsite links. I get enough phishing attempts in email. If stack overflow workflow's included dumping files and projects, then there would be an upload, pastebin or github provided.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. The question especially doesn't deserve the three down votes to remove it from the audit queue.

Comment: Oh, I did not know he was downvoted because of this post. That's unfortunate. I don't think its a question that will *not* be useful to future visitors (sans the missing source code). There will likely be lots of folks who will find that useful because Yet Another Apple Bug Was Released To Production. I just thought it was a bad audit question.

Comment: @jww If you refuse to follow links, that is your own problem. Just skip over the audit review like you would with a question that you don't know anything about. Other people are happy to follow links, especially when there is a bounty of 300. Allow those people to review the question instead of doing it yourself.

Comment: @troop231 - My apologies that I offended you. I was attempting to following site rules on the review. I don't believe arrogance played a role. Also consider: when audits are presented, they don't include context like a 100 point bounty. They are meant to trip us up. Finally, I did not downvote the question. Downvotes are reserved for three particular reasons, and I thought future visitors might find it useful because of Apple bugs (I develop on iOS, too).

Comment: @Abhi - *Not* following links is a safety for everyone, and not just me. If Stack Overflow wanted folks to dump source files and entire projects, then they would have provisions for file uploads, pastebins, or githubs. Maybe I'm mistaken, but I believe its part of the reason for [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And also see *Help others reproduce the problem* at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Hans - "...you got it wrong. Big time wrong. Small odds..." - I disagree. The question was "my code crashes, and here's the files on GitHub". That violates Stack Overflow rules. If I do encounter a similar problem, I can **assure** you my code will **not** be placed on GitHub.

Comment: @jww the rules are "minimal, complete, verifiable". Sometimes it is impossible to be complete and verifiable unless you post a link to code on github. If your code cannot possibly fit within a question on stack overflow, then you must provide a link to externally hosted code or else you have failed to provide enough details about the question. I'm not going to even attempt to help somebody with a problem unless they post enough code to reproduce the issue. As for following external links to github, that's a risk I'm personally willing to take. If the link is to pastebin I'd agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

My original question suggested the review question should be considered for removal from the audit pool. Since then, some answers and comments have wandered from the sites rules and degraded into personal attacks on me. So I'm going to supply an answer that cites Stack Overflow's rules and opposes @Hans' answer.

First, the question should have included relevant source code. This is a site rule and its stated in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask):

> - Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example.
> - If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can
>     *link* to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.

Second, the question did not include a minimal example. This is a site rule and its stated in [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

> When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will
>   get much better answers if you provide code people can use to
>   reproduce the problem. That code should be...
>
> - Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem
> - Complete – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem
> - Verifiable - Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem

Third, there's a Close Reason specifically crafted for the previous rules. Additionally, the Close Reason specifically states "*[questions] must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself***". *(Emphasis Stack Overflow)*.

[image]

Fourth, sometimes the offiste resource is not available or blocked. See, for example, [Imgur.com blocked, what are my options?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/imgur-com-blocked-what-are-my-options). So its essential to keep information with the question.

Fifth, I question the wisdom in promoting offsite links in questions. Stack Overflow acknowledges links can change over time and they have a Flag reason for Answers just for the practice. In addition, its training site users for phishing attempts, so there's a real security concern here.

Sixth, the suggestions that reviewers "cheat" the system by visiting the original question are absurd. The review system provides a valuable service and I am appalled that suggestions are made to cheat it. Cheating the system does not help Stack Overflow, it does not help the reviewer (in this case, me), and it does not help the original poster (in this case, troop231).

Seventh, a bounty does *not* speak to the quality of a question. It's only a witness to the poster's (or another's) desire to obtain an answer to a question.

Eighth, the quality of an answer (in this case, DrBeardface's answer), is distinct form the quality of a question.

Ninth, the process of down voting a question to remove it from the review pool is not fair to the person who posted the question. Down votes are reserved for specific cases, and they *do not* include (1) remove a question from the review pool, or (2) the poster's view differs from my view.

In this case, troop231's question was not a bad question. In fact, anyone familiar with iOS and the endless stream of Apple bugs will know the question likely *will* benefit future users. As another example, I disagree with some of @Hans' comments and and his conclusion, but I did *not* down vote it because it did not meet the criteria.

Tenth, reviewers don't make the rules, we just attempt to follow them. I'm a Computer Science guy who classifies as a *TJ in the [Myers-Briggs type indicator (MBTI)](http://www.myersbriggs.org/my-mbti-personality-type/mbti-basics/). If I enjoyed stretching or misinterpreting rules, or ignoring rules, or manipulating results, then I would have attended law school or gone into politics. As a matter of fact, I recently voted to close one of my own questions because it was a duplicate: [WinRT: How to generate secure random numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142383/winrt-how-to-generate-secure-random-numbers).

Finally, If @Hans assertions are correct, then the site rules need to be changed to conform to his answer.