# How should I review answers with screenshots of code in Low Quality Posts?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts, code

This is related to [Should I review questions with images of code as "looks ok" or "requires editing"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378971/should-i-review-questions-with-images-of-code-as-looks-ok-or-requires-editing), but for Low Quality Posts, which I consider a different situation than Triage.

Just recently I came across an answer in Low Quality Posts. It had a screenshot of the code required to solve the OP's problem. If it was written as text, it would be a nice, high quality answer, but of course, screenshots of code are never quite as useful as code posted as text.

According to [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue):

> **Low quality answers**. Yes, I know the queue is named "low quality posts", but not every minor problem needs to be deleted. Consider first if you can edit - or leave a comment for the author asking for more details, a better explanation, etc. **Only if you can't plausibly imagine anyone putting in the work to fix the post should you opt to delete these kinds of answers.**

It takes quite a bit of work to translate a screenshot of code to plaintext, and it's likely that a mistake will be made in the process. It seems unrealistic to ask a reviewer to do this, so it fits the last paragraph ("Only if you can't plausibly imagine anyone putting in the work to fix the post should you opt to delete these kinds of answers."). This makes me think Recommend Deletion is the right option.

The other side of it is that the answer actually *does* provide a solution to the question asked. It will probably be useful to future visitors of the question, with the downside of copy-pasting not being available. This makes me think Looks OK would be the best option.

There's also the final option of manually translating the screenshot to text. As I previously mentioned, this seems time-consuming and error-prone, but it would drastically increase the quality of the answer if it was done correctly. This makes me think Edit might work out as well.

Which of these three options is correct, Looks OK, Edit, or Recommend Deletion?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Recommend deletion.

The answer isn't very good or useful if it requires you to be able to read code from a screenshot.  Editors run the risk of making copy edit errors which would diminish any value the answer has.

Comment: *"The answer isn't very good or useful if it requires you to be able to read code from a screenshot."* - I disagree. Most of us (with the notable exception of any blind users we have) are capable of reading code in screenshots; for those of us not disabled in a relevant way, code being in a screenshot is merely a nuisance that detracts from an answer's value rather than a dealbreaker that totally destroys the value. As someone seeking an answer, I would rather have to deal with that nuisance than not have an answer at all.

Comment: @MarkAmery:  If someone who is vision impaired is seeking an answer, the nuisance which is an image for sighted users becomes an insurmountable obstacle.  It's *effectively* the same as not having an answer.

Comment: @MarkAmery: [Don't forget about people who's company network blocks the images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261455/imgur-com-blocked-what-are-my-options/)

Comment: @MarkAmery If the poster can get a screenshot of the code, they can probably copy-and-paste the code into the answer.  If for some reason they can't, then they should type it up, and verify it is correct.  This makes it searchable, saves time and avoids transcription errors.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I entirely agree. Nobody here disagrees with what you just said. If you think I disagree, then you're misreading what I've said, because nothing I've said anywhere on this page suggests that.

Answer (score -8):

> The other side of it is that the answer actually does provide a solution to the question asked. It will probably be useful to future visitors of the question

For what it's worth, I'd say this is an edge case. Posting code in screenshots is an obviously unhelpful thing to do, and people who do it anyway are... typically not our finest and most valuable contributors.

But if you are truly in that edge case - if you really do believe that an answer that consists primarily of a screenshot of code adds value to the page - then I'd suggest (carefully!) transcribing it. You suggest this is an unreasonable burden to take on, but surely if you believe the answer is valuable, it's worth putting in a few minutes of work to make it more helpful and to prevent it from being [deleted by other users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382027/1709587)?

By all means leave a suitable reprimand to the answerer, either in your edit summary or in a comment, about how they shouldn't post screenshots of code. It's unhelpful, and an objectionable waste of the time of any nice user who comes along and transcribes it. If the answerer has a pattern of doing it, escalate it to the mods. But I wouldn't suggest ever deleting an answer that you believe is useful and whose problems can be corrected by editing, just because the answer violated a rule.