# What is wrong with this post?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

Just failed [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5431153). As I see it, this is a genuine attempt at answering the question, and there seems to be enough information in the answer to draw a conclusion even without the link. Why is it "very low quality"?

**Update:**
For easier reference, here is a screenshot:

> [image: Screenshot]

Comment: It is marked as spam which I have to agree is far fetched in my opninion...

Comment: I've removed the spam flags from the answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It looks like the user has disappeared. I could be a bit harsh if it's due from a ban resulting from this post...

Comment: check out the [revision of another deleted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17629982/revisions) marked as spam before. It is pretty much the same as the audit

Comment: Though the answer is gibberish if you don't grok the jargon, it looks perfectly legit to me (who doesn't quite grok the jargon).  It could be technically wrong (I can't tell) but it's in no way "poor quality".  Using this as an audit check seems pretty stupid, to put it bluntly.

Comment: @ Hot Licks - I don't think stupidity played a role. Audit questions are selected by a criteria like upvotes and downvotes. No one makes a decision.

Comment: Personally I would've edited it.  There's formatting that would make this answer look a lot better.

Comment: @jww - Someone needs to audit the criteria.  Not deciding is making a decision.  (Every post with a downvote is not "poor quality".)

Comment: @Hot Licks - no disagreement for me. I've been burned a few times by the selections process. Its worse for the person providing the answer: once someone brings up a bad audit, a bunch of community members rush to the question to down vote it so its taken out of the pool.

Comment: @Hot Licks - here's an example of "downvote out of the pool": [Source code on GitHub (failed review)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261431/source-code-on-github-failed-review). The fellow who asked the question got really angry with me when I asked the question be removed from the pool because he got hit with a bunch of down votes (not my intention).